# Where does Info in return value {ok, Child, Info} for supervisor:start_child come from?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor

I see from the Erlang docs that supervisor:start_child can return two different non-error results: {ok, Child} and {ok, Child, Info}. Where does this Info get set? Is it different for simple_one_for_one sups as opposed to others? I haven't been able to find an example / documentation on this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Info` comes from the function that starts the child process (as given in the child specification in the supervisor). Most of the time, that function will eventually call [gen_server:start_link/4](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#start_link-4) which only returns `{ok, Pid}` and never `{ok, Pid, Info}`, so that case only applies when you have a custom function for spawning the process, probably using the functions in [the proc_lib module](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/proc_lib.html).

Processes that don't use a pre-defined behaviour are called "special processes" and are [described in the OTP Design Principles User's Guide](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/spec_proc.html#id72588).

Comment: Ah ok, so it's not a standard thing - I should probably come up with a better way to pass the information then. Thanks.